# How to add having clause to queryset without annotate?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Hello I have this queryset:

```
visitas = 
Visitas_Paciente.objects.filter(fecha__range= g.get('fecha_inicio'), 
g.get('fecha_fin'))).values('paciente_id').annotate(numeros=
Sum('numero')).filter(qNumeroVisitas).order_by('numeros')
```

with this sql equivalent:

```
SELECT `ES_visitas_paciente`.`paciente_id`, 
SUM(`ES_visitas_paciente`.`numero`) AS `numeros` FROM 
`ES_visitas_paciente` WHERE `ES_visitas_paciente`.`fecha` 
BETWEEN 2012-01-01 AND 2013-01-01 GROUP BY 
`ES_visitas_paciente`.`paciente_id` HAVING 
SUM(`ES_visitas_paciente`.`numero`) >= 4 ORDER BY `numeros` ASC
```

the problem is that I dont want the 'numeros' column, I just want the id, something like this query:

```
SELECT
`ES_visitas_paciente`.`paciente_id` 
FROM `ES_visitas_paciente`
WHERE `ES_visitas_paciente`.`fecha` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01'
GROUP BY `ES_visitas_paciente`.`paciente_id`
HAVING SUM(`ES_visitas_paciente`.`numero`) > 4
```

please help me :(

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that it will help, but it's worth mentioning: there is 'defer' function, which will not add defined fields to your select query.  [specs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it does not work, it says: Visitas_Paciente has no field named 'numeros' when I try this: visitas=visitas.defer('numeros')

Comment: ok, i think i have something - add just `.values('paciente_id')`

Comment: that prduce this sql query: SELECT `ES_visitas_paciente`.`paciente_id` FROM `ES_visitas_paciente` WHERE `ES_visitas_paciente`.`fecha` BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2013-01-01' GROUP BY `ES_visitas_paciente`.`id` HAVING SUM(`ES_visitas_paciente`.`numero`) >= 4 ORDER BY SUM(`ES_visitas_paciente`.`numero`) ASC  ... the problem is the group by and only return one result

Comment: sorry, i re-read the question and it looks like it is what you wanted... no?

Comment: the problem is the group by the id of the table but I need group by 'paciente_id', I get that clause when I use `values('paciente_id') in the original queryset but I cant use defer in that situation, so I have to do this:  visitas = Visitas_Paciente.objects.filter(fecha__range=(g.get('fecha_inicio'), g.get('fecha_fin'))).annotate(numeros=Sum('numero')).filter(qNumeroVisitas).order_by('numeros')` and after that `values=values.defer('numeros').values('paciente_id')` the idea is return the id's of the patients whose has more than 4 visits between those dates

Comment: No, I meant - add `.values('paciente_id')` instead defer. This will `visitas = Visitas_Paciente.objects.filter(fecha__range=(g.get('fecha_inicio'), g.get('fecha_fin'))).annotate(numeros=Sum('numero')).filter(qNumeroVisitas).orde‌​r_by('numeros').values('paciente_id')`...

Comment: I tried that but it produce the group by with the id of the table , I restarted the server but is the same, this is very weird, I only get the desire 'group by' when I add values after the first filter, but that produce the query with two results: the paciente_id and 'numeros'

Comment: Sorry, I realize that my comment is wrong - `visitas = Visitas_Paciente.objects.filter(fecha__range=(g.get('fecha_inicio'), g.get('fecha_fin'))).values('paciente_id').annotate(numeros=Sum('numero')).filter(numeros > 4).orde‌​r_by('numeros').values('paciente_id')`. Here we filter by the fecha(date), after this create the `group by paciente_id`, than we make the `Sum` by groups, than we filter it by `numeros>4`, order it. Than we get only 'paciente_id'. Should work (THERE ARE 2 values('paciente_id'))

Comment: It works :D thank you

Comment: @AlexanderB. please write your solution as the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we need to limit the selection. We can do this by adding additional `.values(paciente_id)`. Here is a [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values)
After this we will have

```
visitas = Visitas_Paciente.objects.filter(
    fecha__range=(g.get('fecha_inicio'),g.get('fecha_fin'))
).values(
    'paciente_id'
).annotate(
    numeros=Sum('numero')
).filte‌​r(
    numeros > 4
).orde‌​r_by(
    'numeros'
).values(
    'paciente_id'
)
```

Here we

1. filter by the fecha(date),
2. create the group by paciente_id,
3. make the Sum by groups ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/)),
4. filter it by numeros>4,
5. order it.
6. Than we get only 'paciente_id'.

Be careful - there are 2 values('paciente_id') statements.

Hope it helps!